# How to manage the icons in the top bar (14.04 & metacity)

Tags: 14.04, gnome, icons, desktop-environments, metacity

I've installed Virtual-box and this icon appeared in the desktop top bar.

[image]

I know how to add icons with drag & drop but how to remove one?

When trying to drag&drop it in the desktop trash icon, I have a pop-up saying that I don't have the permission to put it in the trash.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove by drag & drop again or right-click and somethings like remove, etc?

Comment: @KasiyA: Yes, but it triggers a copy of the short-cut on the desktop.

Comment: I mean is: drag into trash.

Comment: Pop-up saying that I don't have the permission to put this in the trash. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while right-mouse clicking on the said icon.

A menu should then appear giving you the options to either **move** it or **remove from panel**.

If it's not worked use both of <kbd>Logo</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. the key <kbd>Logo</kbd> is win logo key on your keyboard.

Comment: Do you know how to reset how to get back to the default settings?

Comment: @COil Type this command `unity --reset-icons` in Terminal.